# htaccess remove the parameter from url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove certain url parameters from the urls. Those parameters have no effect on the content being displayed anymore, but google have a bunch of them indexed.

I would like to redirect them to the base url.
Here are the examples.

From `www.myexamplesite.com/?start=10`
To: `www.myexamplesite.com`

From `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1/?start=10`
To: `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1`

From `www.myexamplesite.com/folder2/?start=10`
To: `www.myexamplesite.com/folder2`

Actually I don't need to have any urls with parameters, so I am wondering if there can be a way to catch and redirect all other possible  parameters from the urls, and only allow some selected ones that I will specify in htaccess.

Examples:
From `www.myexamplesite.com/?param1=10`
To: `www.myexamplesite.com`

From `www.myexamplesite.com/?param1=10&param2=20`
To: `www.myexamplesite.com`

From `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1/?param1=10`
To: `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1`

From `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1/?param1=10&param2=20`
To: `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1`

But for param3 which should be my selected one:

From `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1/?param3=10`
leave untouched: `www.myexamplesite.com/folder1/?param3=10`

**Update**
I actually have already implemented a solution, but my main problem is that it always redirect to the home page and not the appropriate REQUEST_URI...

Here is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^item= 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/manage
RewriteRule .? http://www.myexamplesite.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this rule to strip all query strings except when `param3=` is found in it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)param3= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```