# how to display username as part of url using php

Tags: php

how can I pass a username to display in this format in my URL example http://www. example.com/username instead  of http://www.example.com/?user = username
any help will go a long way, thanks

Comment: You should check out [htaccess remove the parameter from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722694/htaccess-remove-the-parameter-from-url)

Comment: what is the right format for it in htaccess

Comment: Added an answer.  You put the .htaccess into the folder you want to have your url shortening happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can write it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

If you want `/category/username` to simulate `/category.php?user=username`, then:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: I am testing with localhost server using wamp but when test run I got this error message "internal server error"

Comment: this I what I see in apache error log bad argument line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my end.    I can't seem to reproduce the issue.

Comment: its working now yet I got this localhost/mysite/category.php?user=username instead of getting localhost/mysite/category/username.

Comment: I updated my post with how to do that.  Please upvote/mark as solution, it helps a lot.

Comment: I have done this recent one you updated yet it doesn't  change the URL whenever I clicked on the link